# Замена новой строчки на запятую

Tags: python, ip, wireguard

У меня есть файл с ip адресами

- 66.220.144.0/20
- 204.15.20.0/22
- 74.119.76.0/22

и мне нужно сделать так чтобы данные айпи адреса в файле шли через запятую

103.4.96.0/22, 103.4.96.0/22, 69.171.224.0/19

Comment: Если можно, уточните вопрос. У вас адреса в столбик? Адреса представлены с точками перед ними? Адреса просто в стоке? То есть, если можно уточните, входной формат. Так как решений может быть множество и все зависит от того, что у вас в файле с адресами.

Comment: есть файл в котором:   ip enter ip enter

Comment: Тогда вам ответ уже дали. Замените "\n" на ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто замените перевод строки на запятую

```
text = """66.220.144.0/20
204.15.20.0/22
74.119.76.0/22
"""
print(text.replace('\n', ', '))
```

Comment: Спасибо, самый простой способ!

Comment: @SP595 Если это решило вашу задачу приймите ответ  и отметьте его полезным нажав на галочку и стрелочку в верх

Answer (score 0):

Сначала делим на отдельные айпи с помощью split(), а потом через цикл for склеиваем в одну строку.

```
massive = file.split()
res_str = ""
for k in massive:
    res_str += k + ", "
```